# Polymer Starter Kit for Dart

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

I would like to use Polymer Starter Kit (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/) for Dart lang.

Is there a version to Dart or some instructions to use in Dart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Polymer-Starter-Kit is mostly CSS with only a little code (last time I checked about a month ago) and shouldn't be hart to port the few bits manually.

https://github.com/montyr75/polymer_dart_starter_kit is an actual port but it might need some updates - latest commit Nov 25, 2015.

Just found https://github.com/ntaoo/polymer_dart_starter_kit_light which looks more up-to-date. No idea what "light" means here.

Comment: Ok, I am going to see these options.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing. It appears there is no official Polymer Starter Kit for Dart as of writing. As Günter states, your best bet is probably to port it yourself, since it isn't too much code. And besides, we have the [package:js](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) library to make that easier on us.

Also, as mentioned, there are two versions. Here is what the official Polymer site says about them (as of writing):

> Download and extract Polymer Starter Kit to where you want to work. The project comes in two flavours - Light and Full.
>
> Beginners: Try Polymer Starter Kit Light. This doesn't require any extra dependencies nor knowledge of modern front-end tooling. This option is good for prototyping if you haven't build a Polymer app before.
>
> Intermediate - Advanced: Use the full version of Polymer Starter Kit. This comes with all the build tools you'll need for testing and productionising your app so it's nice and lean. You'll need to run a few extra commands to install the tools we recommend but it's worth it to make sure your final app is super optimised.

The latter appears to have build tools that may not be relevant for a Polymer.dart project. I'd say go with the light one if you're going to port it yourself.

Note: I filed an [issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/738) in the starter kit repo. Please follow up there to see if there are plans to support a Dart version.